# Best Option for exporting data from one db to magento db

Tags: php, magento, yii

I have 2 different eCommerce  apps running using same products. one of them is using magentocommerce and other is done in Yii framework. What is the best way to export the products made from Yii framework app to magento app ?

So what i am trying to do is i have my sql table with the products and its details. I want to move it to the magentos db format. Is there any good libraries for this ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the best option is to write a bunch of SQL queries.

Comment: I am not a magento developer. magento seems to have more than 200 tables. so i should learn all the table structure ?

Answer (score 1):

Different frameworks use different structures in their DB for storing stuff. So technically you can't easily do this. For example products in Magento are stored in different interrelated tables using EAV data model ([Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/2_-_magento_concepts_and_architecture/magento_database_diagram)). In my idea (maybe) the easiest way is to prepare a standard CSV file for your products and load it from magento Admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

you can check `Magento` batch processing section which they call *Magento Import/Export Profiles* and can be found [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles).

The easiest way is to export data from your current applications and generate "Magento friendly" `.csv` file containing all your products and import them to your Magento app.

Example file in form of image which can be found on Magento side is not much of a use thus I suggest you export products from your existing Magento application and use it as base template.

Hope you will achieve your goal :)